# IRQ Handling from User Space Linux

Tags: linux, driver, handler, irq, userspace

I'm writting a driver for a synthesized device in an FPGA. The device has several IRQs and have requested them on my driver:

```
irq = platform_get_resource(pdev, IORESOURCE_IRQ, 0);
rc = request_irq(irq, &Custom_driver_handler,IRQF_TRIGGER_RISING , DRIVER_NAME, base_addr);
```

My problem is that i want that the irq_handler calls a function of an user space application. Is there any way to call my user space application from the irq_handler of the driver on kernel space??

I know i could save a flag from the driver and mmap its direction from the user application to polling it, but what i want to know is if there is any faster/more correct way.

Thank you in advance

Comment: Almost twenty years ago this was called the "upcall" in the Linux kernel: http://lkml.iu.edu/hypermail/linux/kernel/9809.3/0922.html. Ten years ago the article was posted https://lwn.net/Articles/127698/ Handling interrupts in user space. And now there is UIO framework:  UIO (User I/O) http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/136274/can-i-achieve-functionality-similar-to-interrupts-in-linux-userspace https://lwn.net/Articles/232575/ https://yurovsky.github.io/2014/10/10/linux-uio-gpio-interrupt/ https://www.osadl.org/fileadmin/dam/rtlws/12/Koch.pdf http://www.hep.by/gnu/kernel/uio-howto/

Comment: As i understand, detecting an interrupt using a UIO driver is making polling to a memory direction. Isn't it??
Example of use of UIO driver :
        int32_t irq_count;
        int fd = open("/dev/uio0", O_RDWR);
        void *map_addr = mmap(NULL, 4096,
                                                PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE,
                                                MAP_SHARED, fd, 0);
         /* Always read exactly 4 bytes! */
         while (read(fd, &irq_count, 4) == 4) {
               printf(Interrupt number %d\n,
                         irq_count);
          }

Comment: no you understanding is not full: this read will not return control back to user program when there is no interrupt: https://lwn.net/Articles/232575/ "*The user-space driver will open the device (/dev/uio0). Reading the device returns an int value which is the event count (number of interrupts) seen by the device; **if no interrupts have come** in since the last read, the **operation will block** until an interrupt happens (though non-blocking operation is supported in the usual way as well).*"

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Linux Interrupt Handling in User Space](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7986260/linux-interrupt-handling-in-user-space)

Answer (score 6):

There are several ways of invoking user-space functions from kernel, usually named upcalls: http://lkml.iu.edu/hypermail/linux/kernel/9809.3/0922.html; check also https://lwn.net/Articles/127698/ "Handling interrupts in user space" and  the http://wiki.tldp.org/kernel_user_space_howto overview from 2008, part ["Sending Signals from the Kernel to the User Space"](http://wiki.tldp.org/kernel_user_space_howto#Sending_Signals_from_the_Kernel_to_the_User_Space).

To make writing drivers easier, there is UIO framework in the kernel now: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/136274/can-i-achieve-functionality-similar-to-interrupts-in-linux-userspace https://lwn.net/Articles/232575/ https://yurovsky.github.io/2014/10/10/linux-uio-gpio-interrupt/ https://www.osadl.org/fileadmin/dam/rtlws/12/Koch.pdf http://www.hep.by/gnu/kernel/uio-howto/

With UIO you can block or poll special file descriptor to wait for interrupt (block by using `read()` syscall; poll with `poll` syscall):   https://lwn.net/Articles/232575/

> On the user space side, the first UIO-handled device will show up as /dev/uio0 (assuming a normal udev setup). The user-space driver will open the device. Reading the device returns an int value which is the event count (number of interrupts) seen by the device; if no interrupts have come in since the last read, the operation will block until an interrupt happens (though non-blocking operation is supported in the usual way as well). The file descriptor can be passed to poll().

`include/linux/uio_driver.h` is available in linux kernel for many years, it is here for [3.](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/include/linux/uio_driver.h?v=3.0) and [4.](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/include/linux/uio_driver.h?v=4.0) versions of kernel.