# Why interrupts are not shown in /proc/interrupts?

Tags: embedded, embedded-linux, zynq

I am trying to use UIO driver to transfer data using AXI DMA from programmable logis (PL) to Processing system (PS) on SOC minized board(ZYNQ 7000 series). I have loaded the minized board with petalinux and on typing

```
cat /proc/interrupts
```

I can see the interrupts number 61 and 62 for the dmas. From my application I have succefully map the uio driver and can write to all the relavent registers as shown below

```
    DMA_Set(DMA_Base_Addr+MM2S_DMACR, 0x00000004);
    DMA_Set(DMA_Base_Addr+S2MM_DMACR, 0x00000004);
    DMA_Set(DMA_Base_Addr+MM2S_DMACR, 0x00000000);
    DMA_Set(DMA_Base_Addr+S2MM_DMACR, 0x00000000);
    DMA_Set(DMA_Base_Addr+MM2S_DMACR, 0x00007000);
    DMA_Set(DMA_Base_Addr+S2MM_DMACR, 0x00007000);
    DMA_Set(DMA_Base_Addr+MM2S_SA,    0x30000000);
    DMA_Set(DMA_Base_Addr+S2MM_DA,    0x30000400);
    DMA_Set(DMA_Base_Addr+MM2S_DMACR, 0x00000001);
    DMA_Set(DMA_Base_Addr+S2MM_DMACR, 0x00000001);
    DMA_Set(DMA_Base_Addr+MM2S_LENGTH,0x30000400);
    DMA_Set(DMA_Base_Addr+S2MM_LENGTH,0x00000400);
```

The regester values of S2MM_DMASR and MM2S_DMASR gives 1002 indicating that the 12 bit of the status register is set, that mean interrupt has occoured. But

```
cat /proc/interrupts
```

on the board still shows interrupt count as 0 for dmas. Further the values of S2MM_DMACR and MM2S_DMACR is 10003 indicating that the 15th bit is 1. On the other hand in the mannual [https://docs.xilinx.com/r/en-US/pg021_axi_dma/S2MM_DMACR-S2MM-DMA-Control-Register-Offset-30h](https://stackoverflow.com) it is clearly mentioned that 15th bit is always 0. Can anyone suggest why this two anomaly?

I have reserved memory in my board by modifying system-user.dtsi file and i get the following in my board

```
New:~$ dmesg |grep eserved
Reserved memory: created DMA memory pool at 0x30000000, size 256 MiB
OF: reserved mem: initialized node buffer@0x30000000, compatible id shared-dma-pool
cma: Reserved 16 MiB at 0x2f000000
Memory: 735840K/1048576K available (7168K kernel code, 243K rwdata, 1904K rodata, 1024K init, 118K bss, 296352K res)
hw-breakpoint: found 5 (+1 reserved) breakpoint and 1 watchpoint registers.
```

I was expecting that the above show increase the interrup number 46 and 15th bit of the control registers to be 0.

The sustem-user.dtsi is below:

```
/include/ "system-conf.dtsi"
/ {
    chosen {
        bootargs = "earlycon clk_ignore_unused uio_pdrv_genirq.of_id=generic-uio rootwait quiet loglevel=0";
        stdout-path = "serial0:115200n8";
    };
      reserved-memory{
    #address-cells=<1>;
    #size-cells =<1>;
    ranges;
    dma_reserved:buffer@0{
        compatible="shared-dma-pool";
        no-map;
        reg=<0x30000000 0x1000000>;
    };
    dma_proxy@0 {
        compatible ="xlnx,dma_proxy";
        dmas = <&axi_dma_0 1>;
        dma-names = "dma1";
        memory-region = <&dma_reserved>;
    };
};


&amba_pl {
    dma1:@dma40400000 {
    compatible = "generic-uio";
    reg = <0x40400000 0x10000>;
    interrupt-parent = <&intc>;
    interrupts = <0 30 4>;
    };
};



&axi_dma_0{
    compatible = "generic-uio";
    linux,uio-name = "dma0";
};

&qspi {
        #address-cells = <1>;
        #size-cells = <0>;
        flash0: flash@0 {
                compatible = "n25q512a","micron,m25p80","jedec,spi-nor";
                spi-max-frequency = <50000000>;
                reg = <0x0>;
                #address-cells = <1>;
                #size-cells = <1>;
        };
};
```

Comment: If an interrupt did occur, what would you expect to happen? Do you have an interrupt service routine (ISR) written that would handle it? Have you told Linux to enable that interrupt? Normally all this would be taken care of by a device driver. Poking registers from user-space doesn't seem the way to go.

Comment: @pmacfarlane Thank you for your comment. The "UIO frame work" seems to work on blocking read once it i s mmap with the registers and memory is assigned as per the link kernel.org/doc/html/v4.14/driver-api/uio-howto.html Can you suggest how to tell linux to enable interrupt? I have written the interupts in the device tree in system-user.dtsi. I have added the system-user.dtsi.

Comment: To enable the interrupt in the kernel you'd need to be running code in the kernel - e.g. a device driver, either built into the kernel, or loaded as a module. And you'd need to provide an interrupt handler that could clear the interrupt and take whatever action is required. It doesn't make much sense (to me) to try to enable an interrupt if you're accessing the device from user-space. What would be the point of it? What would it achieve?

Comment: @pmacfarlane I was thinking UIO is the driver. So I could control the AXi DMA through UIO. No other device driver is necessry. Is it possible, it seems there are references where it claims that it can be done.

Comment: @pmacfarlane when I do command: dmesg | grep AXI nothing is returned. Does it give any clue? It seems AXI is not configured.

Comment: @pmacfarlane The device tree has <&intc> and number 29 and cat /proc/interrupts gives GIC 61. One is AXI interrupt controller and the other is Generic interrupt controller. Do I have write any code in my application to imply that both are same? Else, how operating system would know?

Comment: You might want to read this: [Linux Interrupt Handling in User Space](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7986260/linux-interrupt-handling-in-user-space). It links to quite a few other similar questions too.